# R: filter for rows in a character vector that contain strings with numbers/digits

Tags: r

I am looking for a way to filter a character vector in R. I only want to have those rows left, that contain any number or digit. Rows not containing a number should be filtered out. After I have done the filtering, I would like to extract those numbers. How could I do this?

Comment: Before posting, it, I just want to confirm.  Suppose you have strings like "123", would you filter it out

Comment: No, I do want to have it left. No matter how many digits, I only want to filter out rows that do not contain any digit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `grep` that matches one or more non-numeric (`\\D+`) from the start (`^`) to end (`$`) of string, use the `value = TRUE` and `invert = TRUE` to get the elements that do not match the pattern

```
grep("^\\D+$", v1, value = TRUE, invert = TRUE)
#[1] "az1"  "Abc2" "123"
```

Or use

```
grep("\\d+", v1, value = TRUE) 
#[1] "az1"  "Abc2" "123"
```

---

Suppose if we need to filter out cases where there are only numbers

```
grep("([A-Za-z].*[0-9])|[0-9].*[A-Za-z].*[0-9]", v1, value = TRUE)
#[1] "az1"  "Abc2"
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c("az1", "AB", "Abc2", "123")
```